# Rationalising surds question grade 10

Tags: radicals, rationalising-denominator

I am a student and I need help answering answering this question. I don't know if I should get rid of the 6.

2)Rationalise and simplify

$$\frac{6}{3+\sqrt 40}$$

Thank you and help is appreciated

Comment: Multiply by the fraction $\dfrac{3 - \sqrt{40}}{3 - \sqrt{40}}$ and simplify the denominator to $9 - 40$.

Comment: Do you know what a rational number is? That is the starting point for understanding.

Comment: It is a whole number or fraction or terminating decimal

Comment: OK. So what does the phrase rationalise the denominator mean?  Why is it not rational now?

Comment: Because  a surd is an irrational number

Comment: So we might try multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt {40} $ but this fails. Why?

Comment: Because you have to multiply ${\sqrt 40}$ by 6 and +3 which doesn't make the denominator rational

Comment: The $3$ certainly messes things up. Now recall the difference of squares. What happens to the middle term? How does this help?

Comment: It becomes a so  (9 - 40)

Comment: So you have a sensible thing to multiply by as you lose the irrational part. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for helping me☺

Comment: Nice work here, @Karl, and you too Olivia!

Answer (score 0):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $3-2\sqrt{10}$
which gives 
$$\frac{6}{3+\sqrt 40}=\frac{6(3-2\sqrt{10})}{(3+2\sqrt 10)(3-2\sqrt{10})}=\frac{18-12\sqrt{10}}{9-40}=\frac{12\sqrt{10}-18}{31}$$

Since $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

Comment: I don't know how to use the same method to rationalise and simplify $$\frac{6}{3+\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: For general $(a+\sqrt b) $ in denominator multiply by $(a-\sqrt b)$ to rationalise..Like your example in comments rationalise like I have told you using difference of squares...Answer is $3-\sqrt3$